# upgrade from .NET 2.0 to .NET 6

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http 2.2.0

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstraction 2.2.0

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions

Do we need to upgrade these nuget packages when we upgrade from .NET 2.2 to .NET 6

Comment: Since they appear to be part of ASP.NET Core itself, why wouldn't you?

Comment: You're migrating from ASP.NET Core 2.2 which reached End Of Life in 2019 to ASP.NET Core 6. Yes, you do need to upgrade all packages. .NET Core 2.2 reached End Of Life in 2019. There are a lot of changes since so expect several things to break or need changes too. EF Core 2.x had significant limitations and used client-side evaluation silently even eg for grouping. That was disabled in EF Core 3.1 and now results in exceptions. You may have to rewrite several queries that can't be translated to SQL

Answer (score 0):

No. Check out the [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#remove-obsolete-package-references) doc especially the *Remove obsolete package references* section:

> A large number of NuGet packages aren't produced for ASP.NET Core 3.0. Such package references should be removed from your project file.

Based on the fact that the latest version of mentioned packages is 2.2.x with last update of 2019 ([Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http), [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions) is even older) this packages are clear candidates for such removal.

Do not forget to check other migration docs which could be relevant, like [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 3.0 to 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/30-to-31?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) and [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 3.1 to 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-60?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio).