# Successor of Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures (Package is Depreciated)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I have a ViewModel in which I use a IEnumerable. The project itself is a class library. Now when adding the IEnumerable my IDE suggested to install

```
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures" Version="2.2.0" />
```

However when building the project afterwards I get an error saying that the package has a problem with a referenced assembly.

Assembly 'FMH.Web.Mvc.UI' with identity 'FMH.Web.Mvc.UI, Version=2023.8.11.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions' with identity 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'

Additionally the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures is depreciated as shown on [Nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/)

Why is there a problem with the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, the package is not referenced by me?

I followed up the information on Nuget as well on Microsoft to find the "right" package but no luck.

Comment: See ASP.NET Core upgrade guides. ASP.NET Core is not "distributed" via nuget packages since 3.0, so you need either use corresponding SDK or add `FrameworkReference` (as in the duplicate)

Comment: In case someone stumbles across the same problem. Microsoft has moved a lot of these packages that we had to reference in the past into the framework. So the answer is "There is no successor of that package".
All you need to do is to change the project type from Microsoft.NET.Sdk to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web. This will pull in all the references needed and you no longer need the package explicitly.

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

PS: Don't forget to remove the package reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures , it is no longer needed.

Comment: Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75665708/2501279) might be helpful, but since it does not have upvotes I can't add it a duplicate.